# Angular Google Maps (AGM) Core loading problem

Tags: angular

Loading mapsAPILoader works only when the component is inited the second time.

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => { console.log('loaded') });
```

So if I loaded once in app.component then again in form component it will work.

why it doesn't load on the first time.

Comment: Where are you calling the load from initially and the second time? At which lifecycle hook?

Comment: if I call the load in the rootComponent OnInit and then load it again in a subComponent also OnInit, it works. But it is weird that if I only call it once anywhere rootComponent or subComponent Oninit it doesn't work until I destroy that subComponent and reopen it .

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve but i don't know if it's the best or ideal way to do it

```
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    //Called after every check of the component's or directive's content.
    //Add 'implements AfterContentChecked' to the class.
    if (!this.isApiLoaded) {
        this._loader.load().then(() => {
            this.isApiLoaded = true;
            console.log('loaded')
        });
    }
}
```

As you can read in the comments of AfterContentChecked it constantly checks all the page but in this way you can check for the API if its loaded and set a variable to ensure that the loader is not called multiple times.